# Get into SQL Server 2008 with no management studio and no sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I got office program. This program stores his data in SQL Server 2008 Express, but there is no management studio and no sqlcmd. How can i get into pure SQL tables, to use them in my plugin.

Comment: Are you asking how to query SQL Server from within a Microsoft Office application (i.e., Excel) macro?

Comment: I must analize database and then query SQL Server, but from my own application.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still trying to understand what you're doing. You're saying there's some application that stores it's data in SQL Server, and you're writing another application/plugin that needs to query that data? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. That's correct. Right now i am trying to install sql server 2012, to query data from sql server 2008 with 2012 management studio, but i am not sure if it will work. Of course i will query data from sql server 2008 later with JDBC from my aplication, but first i must analize tables, columnts etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download SSMS 2012 or 2014 which is a full seperate download and then use it to access tables, etc

link: [ssms 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062)

can't comment on what/ how your plugin is.

Answer (score 0):

osql from the command line should work as well as SQL Server Management Studio...either way you have to download the SQL Server client.  TOAD also has a free tool for working with the database.

Comment: osql was replaced by sqlcmd and is deprecated in [SQL 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879341.aspx).

Comment: @MikeFal: `sqlcmd` replaced `osql` in SQL Server **2005**, actually ...

Answer (score 0):

You can download some free administration tool, for example, [SQL Manager Lite for SQL Server](http://mssqlmanager.com). It does not require additional client libraries.